# Inserting users into WordPress table using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add users to the `wp_users` table in WordPress using PHP. I think I have the right code (or maybe I don't) but I can't seem to get it to run. So either I have done something wrong or I am a bit confused (well I am definitely confused).

Basically I have this code in a PHP file under WordPress plugins. I am then entering the code in the URL as:

```
localhost:8888/xxx/xxx/plugins/register_user.php.
```

Will this work or what do I need to do? When I check MySQL afterwards it has not entered the user. Am I doing something blatantly wrong?

I have never done this before, and don't know PHP very well so please explain things clearly and for someone who is stupid. Here is the code.

```
<?php # Script 9.3 - register.php

$page_title = 'Register';

add_action('init', 'create_user');

function create_user() {
    $username = 'username123';
    $password = 'pasword123';
    $email = 'drew@example.com';

    $user = get_user_by( 'email', $email );
    if( ! $user ) {

        // Create the new user
        $user_id = wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email );
        if( is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
            // examine the error message
            echo( "Error: " . $user_id->get_error_message() );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To Create a user in wordpress you can use the function WP Create User.  You seem to be complicating the code a little bit.  You can read about creating users in the Wordpress Codex [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user)

```
<?php wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email ); ?>
```

Here is how wordpress handles it in the wp-admin/upgrade-functions.php:

```
$user_id = username_exists( $user_name );
if ( !$user_id and email_exists($user_email) == false ) {
    $random_password = wp_generate_password( $length=12, $include_standard_special_chars=false );
    $user_id = wp_create_user( $user_name, $random_password, $user_email );
} else {
    $random_password = __('User already exists.  Password inherited.');
}
```

Hope This Helps